# Image path error in Tablet device

Tags: c#, path, tablet

When creating my project I have referenced the image path as `@..\..\Assets\no_picture_available1.gif` was working fine, when I installed my application in other machine it says the path not available.

I tried using this one

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"..\..\Assets\no_picture_available1.gif";
```

It shows the path as

```
"F:\\WindowsApp\\UI\\bin\\Debug..\\..\\Assets\\no_picture_available1.gif"
```

How can I set the path to `Assets` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue, problem was with the Assets path,
when debug i set the path as different and while in release mode i set the different path.

```
string pathdir = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Assets\\no_picture_available1.gif");

#if DEBUG
       return pathdir = @"../../Assets/no_picture_available1.gif";

#else
        return pathdir;
#endif
```